# JComboBox mueve la posición de jPanel

Tags: java, netbeans, layout

Estoy intentando hacer un menú desplazando un jPanel a una posición no visible y regresándolo a una posición visible en el jFrame. Este menú tiene un formulario y este contiene un jComboBox, al hacer clic en éste, cambia la posición del jPanel devolviéndolo a la parte no visible del jFrame, sólo pasa con este último, los demás elementos del formulario no causan este error. Adjunto las siguientes imágenes:

jFrame sin menú desplegado:
[image: jFrame sin menu desplegado]

jFrame menú desplegado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer clic en el comboBox el menú se oculta.

Según lo que he leído es puede ser el layout que uso.

El proyecto lo estoy desarrollando en netbeans con el lenguaje JAVA, y el layaout que utilizo es "absolute layaout"

Link código fuente: https://github.com/CarlosMateoM/Planes_Academicos

---

No he dado con el problema. Hasta el momento estaba utilizando Netbeans
12.2, pero probé en Netbeans
8.2 y en este el JComboBox
no tiene ese comportamiento extraño, además ejecuté el programa por consola y tampoco ocurre. Por lo que concluyó que debe ser un error o una mala configuración de Netbeans.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta y ademas no podemos ayudarte porque no has pasado el código. por otro lado, dices que al presionar el JComboBox se oculta el panel, esto puede ser porque le diste el mismo evento de cerrarse al JComboBox que al botón de la izquierda, también no es necesario que le des evento al JComboBox, al final cuando presiones el botón de REGISTRAR obtén el texto que hallas seleccionando con `getSelectedItem` y no es necesario estar cambiando una variable cada que cambie el ítem seleccionado del JComboBox, pero sin código solo podemos aportar ideas sin base solida.

Comment: Aprovecha para hacer el [tour] y lee [ask] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por las sugerencias, lo tendré en cuenta la próxima. se que no me explique bien, pero por lo que dices, lograste entender, para descartar de lo que mencionas el JComboBox no tiene ningún evento, la obtención del dato seleccionado se hace con el metodo nombrado ``` lang-java getSelectedItem``` incisto que a mi parecer es la configuración del layout. El código no lo subi directamente aquí por ser muy largo, ahora se me ocurre subirlo a GitHub a compartir el link del repositorio. Muchas gracias por responder, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Hola, hace un rato copie el repositorio, pero no he encontrado el error que dices, en mi caso el código se ejecuta correctamente, y el panel no se cierra al dar click en el JComboBox, este despliega la lista y todo lo demás funciona también. El JComoBox no se relaciona con el evento del botón de flecha, por lo que no sabría decirte el problema aun... Recuerda que puedes publicar tu respuesta si lo logras solucionar...

Comment: Efectivamente, lo probe con el ide de netbeans 8.2 y no me surgio el problema. El IDE da el error.